# Jboss AS7 Deployment warning : does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

Im getting the below warning when deploy the .war in the jboss AS7. Any idea?

> (MSC service thread 1-4) Class Path entry commons-beanutils.jar in "/content/test-1.0.0.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts-1.2.9.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

PS. commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar is already in the lib folder.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is just a warning that you can in most cases safely ignore.

What it tells you is that in your struts-1.2.9.jar has in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
in Class-Path reference to "commons-beanutils.jar" and that this file/jar cannot be referenced.
But given that you have commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar there everything will work fine.

To get rid of the warning you can do two things:

- rename commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar to commons-beanutils.jar or
- open struts-1.2.9.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and remove that Class-Path element.

But as I said this is mostly informative warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So for the moment I will ignore it as this is not harm for my deployment. Anyway, I cannot do the both ways u suggested,  as
1. Im using maven to build the project and I need to define the correct version of the beanutil.
2. it is not advice to remove the MANIFEST.MF as I will be continuously connecting to the external repo to get the struts version.

Comment: Dear @Tomaz Cerar , I designed my project as a EAR includes some JAR, WAR, and EJB modules. I have the same problem. Do you think that this problem is due to scopes in maven configuration? As you know we have some scopes (compile, provided, ...)