# How to suppress class path entry warnings while deploying war on JBOSS EAP 6.2.0?

Tags: java, spring, web-deployment, jboss6.x

When I deploy a war on JBOSS EAP6.2.0 I get

```
13:08:59,402 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxp-api.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncconsole.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,403 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jax-qname.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncconsole.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,403 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015960: Class Path entry servlet.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncconsole.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,767 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_cs.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,768 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_de_DE.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,768 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_es.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,769 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_fr.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,769 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_hu.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,770 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_it.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,770 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,771 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,772 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pl.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,775 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,780 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ru.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,785 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,792 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derby.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,798 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_cs.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,802 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_de_DE.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,807 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_es.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,813 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_fr.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,818 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_hu.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,823 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_it.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,828 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,835 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,840 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pl.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,845 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,850 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ru.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,856 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,862 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,867 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbynet.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbyrun.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,872 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_cs.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,878 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_de_DE.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,883 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_es.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,888 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_fr.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,895 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_hu.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,900 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_it.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,904 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,909 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,916 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pl.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,921 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,926 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_ru.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,929 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:08:59,950 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/derbytools.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:09:00,000 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/logadapter.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:09:00,001 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry lib/wlfullclient.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/logadapter.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:09:00,144 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jaxp-api.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:09:00,146 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry jax-qname.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:09:00,152 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015960: Class Path entry servlet.jar in /C:/Kony/KonySync/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/content/syncservice.war/WEB-INF/lib/saaj-api.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

How do I suppress these warnings?

Comment: Removing class path references from manifest file did not help !!!

Answer (score 1):

Removing Class-Path entry from MANIFEST file under derby.jar!/META-INF worked for me.
Ref: [Jboss AS7 Deployment warning : does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681870/jboss-as7-deployment-warning-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jar-for-a-class-path-re)

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue with a jar we are using that itself is requiring (via Maven `pom.xml`) some `provided` (means the server should provide it and they are not included in the jar itself) jars.
We do not use the functionality (classes) that needs these jars and thus it is not an issue.

We currently just ignore it.

I guess manipulating the contained `pom.xml` and `foo.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST` by removing the reference entries could be a workaround.

If one uses *logback* you could write a log filter to specifically filter it out e.g. via some regexp `^\QJBAS015960: Class Path entry \E(somelib-1.2.3|somelib2|somelib3)\.jar.*`.

Another option, if you can manipulate the referencing jar/project, is, to split the project into separate ones, each implementing more dedicated functionality, so the dependencies on the referenced libs will be less for each (sub)project and thus only the really required ones may be left.