# Exclude class path reference from MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x, maven-3

I was getting some `WARN`ings while trying to deploy the EARs in JBoss 7.1.1.

```
15:41:32,028 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) Class Path entry lib/commons-fileupload-1.0.jar in "/C:/myEar.ear/myWar.war"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

The issue is clearly explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681870/jboss-as7-deployment-warning-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jar-for-a-class-path-re) SO thread.

I tried removing the refernces from the MANIFEST.MF file and no more warnings appreared there after.

My question is, is there anything I can try to exclude this class path from MANIFEST.MF without removing that manually?

I was looking for a way, somehow I can do that while taking the mvn build.I'm using maven 3.

Comment: Are you looking for a Java program that accepts an EAR as input and produces an EAR without the Class-Path as output?  Or are you looking for how to do that in your build?  If yes, what build system are you using?  Or what are you asking for specifically?

Comment: @bkail : Thanks.I was looking for a way, somehow I can do that while taking the mvn build. Updated the question.

Comment: That's useful information.  Unfortunately, I don't have an answer, so I've added maven tags with the hope someone else knows.

Comment: Do you have modules entries in your ear configuration of the maven-ear-plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise You mean in the pom file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it resolved:

From the maven documentation [Generating a manifest classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-manifest-guide.html)
I have set the property `addClasspath` to `false`. Now there is no warnings in the console.

```
        <manifest>
          <packageName>blabla</packageName>
                        <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
                        ....
                        <addExtensions>false</addExtensions>
                        ....
        </manifest>
```